# Which CMS with dynamic news and a build in media gallery is fast in install and configure?

Tags: php, asp.net, content-management-system

I'm looking for an webbased system (likely a CMS?) with the following properties:

- Allows to create dynamic news items on a news-page based on a simple login
  authentication
- Contains a dedicated media gallery (images+videos) where the content has to be supplied through the site (not through admin functions or other backend systems) using simple login authentication with (possibly) preset account data. Just being able to embedd media in news items (e.g. user-created pages) is not sufficient.
- Other than the news and media gallery needs to support static pages.
- It should be fast and easy to install and configure
- Either based on PHP/MySQL or ASP.Net/MySQL/SQL-Server. Must run on standard webhosters.
- If possible: Completely customizable layout (need to reuse existing CSS style sheets)
- Should not need excessive coding (I'm happy with some coding but not writing it from scratch)

I'm more happy with a small system that can be extended by some coding than an overblown system where you need to configure everything down. Any suggestions?

Comment: I extended my answer. NexGEN is just one example for a Wordpress gallery plugin. Besides you can also write your own, but I don't think you'll have to.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer.
NextGen uses Admin functions to get the images online, which I don't want and this solution would be quite complex. First wordpress, then NextGen which also has further dependencies.
And writing a good media gallery with my requirements would be a huge undertaking. I think I'll likely look for a good standalone media gallery and develop the news page part myself (which is trivial) if nobody comes up with something better.

Answer (score 2):

Just get [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/)! You can also get it hosted, in case you don't want to run it yourself. It sounds like it's the most easy fit to your requirements.

(**Updated, 2009-10-26:**) [NexGEN](http://alexrabe.de/wordpress-plugins/nextgen-gallery/) - an example for a gallery plugin for Wordpress.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this, but hit my daily limit. Wordpress is the way to go in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with wordpress. I did already look at it a few days ago. However either it does not have a good media gallery or I have completely overlooked that functionallity. I'm looking for an integrated dedicated gallery page/solution. Not some simple images embedded in a posting.